# how to include multiple liquibase changelog xml files in YAML format

Tags: xml, yaml

I want to convert the below xml code into YAML.

```
<include file="changelog/01-create-person.xml"
         relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

<include file="changelog/02-nullable-age.xml"
         relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```

Can someone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems that works only like this

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      file: db/changelog/1.0.0/changelog.yaml
  - include:
      file: db/changelog/1.1.0/changelog.yaml
```